# How to search a php array and get the corresponding key value if it matches

Tags: arrays, associative

I need to search a multi dimensional array in php and return the corresponding value of another key if my key and value match

```
$my_array = array(    
    0 =>  array(  
        "name"   => "john",  
        "id"    =>  4  
    ),  
    1   =>  array(  
        "name" =>  "mark",  
        "id" => 152  
    ), 
    2   =>  array(  
        "name" =>  "Eduard",  
        "id" => 152  
    )
);

if (array_search(152, array_column($my_array, 'id')) !== FALSE){
  I want the corresponding key and value here
i.e name="mark" in this case
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One interesting way is by using array_unique woth a SORT_REGULAR option to remove the duplicates first then you can use this list of none duplicates to remove from the array leaving only duplicates remaining.

print_r(array_unique($array, SORT_REGULAR));

Answer (score 0):

you can easily loop through your multidimensional array with foreach loop and comparing the id value for every array with your value like this.

```
<?php
$array = array(
    0 =>  array(  
        "name"   => "john",  
        "id"     =>  4  
    ),  
    1   =>  array(  
        "name" =>  "mark",  
        "id" => 152  
    ), 
    2   =>  array(  
        "name" =>  "Eduard",  
        "id" => 152 
    )
);

foreach($array as $arr){
    if($arr['id'] === 152){
        echo $arr['name'];
        break;
    }
}
?>
```